# Xcode App won't load view sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

my project runs without storyboards, so im loading my view inside AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;
    self.window.rootViewController = [[SYLoginController alloc] init];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

It used to work on iPhone 6 sim 9.3 but now, on all simulators it only shows a black screen. But on my iPhone 6 Device it works. Whereas on another iPhone 6 it also shows a black screen. Those two iPhones are literally the same 16gb iPhone 6 bought at nearly the same time.

In `SYLoginController`s `viewDiDLoad` I'm logging the text of one of the buttons.  Only on my device it prints the text, on all simulators and the other iPhone it prints (null), so i assume that the xib is not properly loaded.

`SYLoginController` is a `UIViewController`, and the related xib holds a UIView with its FilesOwner set to `SYLoginController`. I really can't see why it only works on this particular device.  Also i tried `[[SYTabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SYLoginController" bundle:nil]`, this also does not work...

Comment: Do you tried cleanning (Cmd-K) or uninstall app in real device before running project? It should not work in real device too.

Comment: I tried cleaning the project, i tried cleaning derivedData, ich also uninstalled the app several times. One iPhone works, the other does not nor does the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to wrap it arround a Navigation Controller?

```
SYLoginController *syVC = [[SYLoginController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SYLoginController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] syVC];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Also check again if Custom Class is set to SYLoginController in the XIB-File. And the View is connected to the Files Owner.

Comment: I tried it, now its a navigation controller (you can see the nav bar) with a black screen...

Comment: Yes, you can hide the Navigationbar. But strange... Check the XIB-File. Print out the Views Frame Size. Give the SyLoginController an other backgroundcolor.

Comment: I can use self.window.backgroundColor to set the backgroundcolor of the view, but it seems that the xib is not loaded. Strangely on my iphone it works.